# Why use Call Back instead of directly calling the function?

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

While going through this [CallBack Function](http://opensourceforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/) article/code (under the heading **A simple callback function**) I found that callback is nothing but simple function calls, then why not simply call that function instead of calling it through a function pointer which has been passed as a parameter? Please tell me if I am wrong in understanding it. This question is based on the learning at initial stage about the concept seeking for some simple clarification.

Comment: Sometimes you don't know the name of the function you want to call ahead of time.

Comment: @AndyG Can you please explain or post some link. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more context to your question.  There are a lot of places where callbacks make sense.  Provide an example of where you think it makes less sense to use callbacks than it does to just call a function.  The main use case of callbacks is to address asynchronous-ness.

Comment: Dependency injection

Comment: @zero298 Well I've just started studying it and the question is based on the initial learning of the concept - I am looking for clarification for that in the question itself.

Comment: This is a simple example but in real life your current thread might not know when it is the correct moment to call the callback function. For example, the main thread doesn't know when a mouse-click event occurs and it cannot always scan the mouse state because it has more important tasks to perform. So, your main function will tell the "mouse-scanner" thread which callback function to call when a click event takes place.

Comment: @Gaurav: You're basically asking "what is this feature useful for". Well, the answer is "lots of stuff". There are dozens of uses for callbacks in C and C++. None of these uses are more correct than any other. It's like asking "what is adding integers useful for?"

Comment: *"why not simply call that function instead of calling it through a function pointer"* - because you can be given different function pointers to different functions so you don't know which function is going to be called when you are writing the program, the decision is made by the program while it is running.

Comment: @Galik so why can't we just make a switch-case statement in that function and pass the choice as a parameter?

Comment: @Gaurav Because the person who writes the function doesn't get to choose what to do. They don't know in advance what callback-function is needed. That choice is made by a different person who writes the callback-function. That's is why the *pointer* to the callback-function has to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is tagged with C++, the simplest callback example I can think of comes from C. It is a C-style `qsort` function.

Imagine yourself implementing an array sorting function. You want the function to be able to take an array of any type and any size. So, what would be the arguments to such a function? First, you need to know the start of the array. Second, you need to know the size of the array. Third, you need to know the size of a single element of the array. And forth, given to elements, your `qsort` would need to know if one is bigger than another! The only way to know this for your generic function would be to call some other function, but which one? You would have to accept a pointer to this comparison function as an argument and call it each time you need to compare two elements. Such comparison function is a callback.

Comment: As always, may the venerable downvoter explain the reasons behind downvoting?

Comment: I don't know why, but maybe it is because you mentioned C, and not C++ (your first sentence). But you can always use [`std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) and remove that paragraph (I suspect that may have tripped people up).

Comment: @Rakete1111 a donwnvoter is within their right, of course, but I disagree. I used `qsort` as a simple, and usually familiar, concept which shows the need for callback functions. If somebody can't see beyond C... Well, I will not argue with them.

Comment: Yeah, I found it weird too. Always comment folks, or no one is able to improve :P

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may be passing a function (or function-object/lambda) that needs to be stored and called later. Sometimes the callback needs to be passed through multiple layers of functions before it it called. Sometimes it needs to be stored in a container (like `std::map`) and only be called much later by code that has no idea what you put into the container.

There are *many* good reasons why callbacs can't just be a simple static call of a pre-declared function. You may not even know the `this` pointer at the time you write the code to call it (for example).